# How to avoid the error undefined method 'mail' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

If I leave the input box blank. I get this error everytime. I don't want it to make new record when it's blank. when not,  I want it to make new record.

this input box is nested and the code of controller is written like this to avoid error

```
  def create
    # Check if there is any contact info added
    if params[:girl][:contact_attributes][:mail].empty?
      params[:girl].delete(:contact_attributes)
    end

    @girl = Girl.new(params[:girl])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @girl.save
        format.html { redirect_to @girl, notice: 'Girl was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @girl, status: :created, location: @girl }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @girl.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

view is like this

```
<%= form_for(@girl) do |f| %>
....

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mail %><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :contact_attributes, @girl.contact do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.text_field :mail %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
....
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my model

```
class Girl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_one :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
  attr_accessible :id, :name_en, :name_ja, :gender_id, :contact_attributes, :photo, :tag_list

  searchable do 
    text :name_en, :name_ja
    text :contact do 
      contact.mail 
    end 
  end

    has_attached_file :photo,
     :styles => {
       :thumb=> "100x100>",
       :small  => "400x400>" } 

    acts_as_taggable_on :tags
    acts_as_commentable

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set

```
@girl = Girl.new
```

inside your else block, just before

```
format.html { render action: "new" }
```

The error happens because you render the new template and inside it the form_for(@girl) gets a nil object - @girl. In order to render the line `<%= f.label :mail %><br />` it tries to call the mail method on the given @girl object in order to get its default value. Since the @girl object is nil and not set in the create action before you render the new template you get this error.

**UPDATE:**

I misunderstood your situation in the answer on the first part of this post. The solution in my opinion is redirecting to the new girl path instead of just rendering the new action. While rendering only renders the view redirecting will make a full-stack request process. Assuming you have the route new_girl_path set you should replace `format.html { render action: "new" }` with

```
format.html { redirect_to new_girl_path }
```

You can run `` `rake routes `` and see what named routes you have set.

Comment: umm I still get the same error. Parameteres are {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fz6rQaDLUK4hEl79BnSpSuHr3/kC/HvJIhE6IYBdWxA=",
 "girl"=>{"id"=>"",
 "name_en"=>"testy",
 "name_ja"=>"testyy",
 "gender_id"=>"1",
 "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000c240688 @original_filename="Chrysanthemum.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"girl[photo]\"; filename=\"Chrysanthemum.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120713-25018-tng5rn>>,
 "tag_list"=>"tastag testag2"},
 "commit"=>"Create Girl"}

Comment: The easiest thing to do is: Instead of rendering action new just redirect_to new_girls_path (assuming you have that route set)

Comment: I'm writing this in my Girl model in order to use tag search system. Does this matter?   searchable do 
    text :name_en, :name_ja
    text :contact do 
      contact.mail 
    end 

  end

Comment: ahhh,, found it!! If I take that part off, it works... How can I remain it and make this workable?????

Comment: did you try to redirect_to new_girl_path instead of rendering the new action? This should also solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried that, but it's still same same :( it seems my Girl model is doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

I problem is the following few lines of code.

```
if params[:girl][:contact_attributes][:mail].empty?
  params[:girl].delete(:contact_attributes)
end
```

If mail is empty in user contact you have removed the contact attributes and created only the user object.

So if you call @girl.contact you will get nil.

I don't know why you have removed the contact attributes.If you still want to do it you need to add  one more line.

```
  if @girl.save
    format.html { redirect_to @girl, notice: 'Girl was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @girl, status: :created, location: @girl }
  else
    #Assuming you have the association like: user has_one contact
    @user.build_contact
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @girl.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

And one more thing

```
<%= f.fields_for :contact_attributes, @girl.contact do |contact| %>
```

can be simply written as

```
<%= f.fields_for :contact do |contact| %>
```

Comment: Thanks!!  but now input box disappeared. Is it because contact record is null?

Answer (score 0):

Replace same line of code with 
`<%= form_for( :girl, :url => {:action => :create}) do |f| %>`

Comment: umm It didn't help :( still the same

Comment: Check database table, is your records are inserted in table?

Comment: Please check my edited question. I added my model. it seems its doing something wrong!

Comment: if I take out 'searchable' method from Girl model. This completely works. but it disables acts_as_taggable